# python merge comma delimited, pipe delimited, space delimited

Tags: python, merge

1st File: Comma Separated File

```
LastName, FirstName, Gender
```

2nd File: Pipe delimited File

```
LastName|FirstName|Gender
```

3rd File: Space Delimited File

```
LastName Gender First Name
```

Using Python 2, I need to merge all these files and then output the result in a single delimited file. How to achieve this? Also, if I want to Sort by last name ascending and output to another file, Sort by Gender and output to another file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Looks like homework....

Comment: This is what I am trying with open('space_delimeted.txt', 'r') as in_file:
 with open('merged_file.txt','w') as out_file:
  reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=' ')
  for row in reader:
   print row
   data_dict["first_name"]  = row[0]
    data_dict["last_name"]   = row[1]
    data_dict["middle_name"] = row[2]
    data_dict["gender"]    = row[3]
    data_dict["provider_type"] = row[5]
    data_dict["date_of_birth"] = datetime.strptime(row[4],'%m-%d-%Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    out_file.write(json.dumps(data_dict)). I don't think this solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out using Pandas library and it made my life much easier.

I just did merged_frame = pd.concat([dfpipe,dfspace,dfcomma], ignore_index=True). The only issue that is left is to do with the date format display.

unsorted_header_frame.to_csv('output_file.txt',date_format='%m/%d/%Y',index=False)

When i export to csv, the date_format is correctly exported. But when I just print the data frame on the terminal window , the dates are displayed in %Y-%m-%d, any suggestion on how to get the display in %m/%d/%Y format?